# Mapping Piwigo on Docker to the Host machine's LAN address

Tags: networking, docker, configuration

I have a Piwigo website running on docker accessible at 192.168.99.100:32XXX from the docker host -- Mac (10.0.0.5). Mac is connected to a netgear router. I need to set up port forwarding on my netgear router so that this can be accessed from the outside world.

Outside world -> netgear router -> port forwarding to mac -> mac mapped to piwigo running on docker.
Is this a good way to set it up? Does it need a reverse proxy like set up on Mac to achieve this? Or can I directly map the Piwigo on docker IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map to Piwigo on the docker ip

Comment: Thanks Aurelien. I can only access piwigo ip - 192.168.99.100:32343 from the Mac (docker host). From a second machine on the LAN (ipad) i couldnt open the site. I am getting a "could not open page..server stopped responding." message. Is there a way to check the Piwigo image to see if a web request was recorded?

Comment: Yes with `docker logs container_id`. You can get the container id with `docker ps -a`

Comment: Thanks again. I was able to get it working by setting up a nginx reverse proxy on the mac to forward requests to the 192.168.X.X address. Now i can map the mac ip to the router.